# Where claused based on value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerquery

I Have a (read only) access to a mssql database where i want to do a Select based on a where statement that is stored in table.

the result of

```
SELECT c.collectionsql 
FROM dbo.collections  AS c 
where c.description = '9-nummers laatste 9 maanden geen afzet'
```

is

> where (Article.demand13 <= 0) and (Article.demand14 <= 0) and (Article.demand15 <= 0) and (Article.demand16 <= 0) and (Article.demand17 <= 0) and (Article.demand18 <= 0) and (Article.demand19 <= 0) and (Article.demand20 <= 0) and (Article.demand21 <= 0) and (Article.demand22 <= 0) and (Article.demandClass <= 7) and (Article.bufferConstant <= 0) and (Article.averageDemand >= 0.01) and ((Article.code >= '900000' and Article.code <= '999999'))

my try -->

```
 Declare @query Nvarchar(max)

set @query ='Select * from dbo.article as Article ' + (SELECT c.collectionsql 
FROM dbo.collections  AS c 
where c.description = '9-nummers laatste 9 maanden geen afzet'
 )

exec ( @query  )
```

i'm getting a blank result. probably due to the "Exec" part. 
is there a easier way of doing a Select based on a concatenate?

---

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Article  AS Article 
where (Article.demand13 <= 0) and (Article.demand14 <= 0) and (Article.demand15 <= 0) and (Article.demand16 <= 0) and (Article.demand17 <= 0) and (Article.demand18 <= 0) and (Article.demand19 <= 0) and (Article.demand20 <= 0) and (Article.demand21 <= 0) and (Article.demand22 <= 0) and (Article.demandClass <= 7) and (Article.bufferConstant <= 0) and (Article.averageDemand >= 0.01) and ((Article.code >= '900000' and Article.code <= '999999'))
```

gives aprox 243 rows of date from dbo.article. problem is that the query stored in te table dbo.collections gets changed every month. This data i'm trying to get into Excel Power Pivot.

Comment: you where clause should be able to link c.description to whatever table your querying that holds lookup values. IF you are looking to do numeric comparison then I suggest you revise your query to reflect same. As descrption being a varchar column will NOT do numeric compares.

Comment: Hello Pwilcox, I'm here to learn so feedback is much appriciated. my error is that i'm getting an empty result.

Comment: so your general query syntax is gonna be something like where c.description in (select description_2 from table_2) ; this will work on exact matches i.e. c.description matches exactly description_2

Comment: so this would be beter syntax?-->
where c.description in ('9-nummers laatste 9 maanden geen afzet')

Comment: @Tom, if `SELECT c.collectionsql FROM dbo.collections  AS c where c.description = '9-nummers laatste 9 maanden geen afzet'` returns no rows, the `@query` variable will be `NULL` and this is a possible reason for this _blank result_.

Comment: A good step in debugging dynamic SQL is to print it before executing. This sounds like a + NULL problem, which makes the entire thing moot (since you're not getting errors). Either by doing a `PRINT @query` or a `RAISERROR(@query, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT` should give some insight.

Comment: You seem to have some serious normalization problems here. You have demand1, demand2 etc. This violates 1NF by using repeating groups. That should be spun off to a second table.

Comment: print en raiseerror both give no error's but also no data.
wen trying in powerpivot i get this error: The SQL statement is invalid. No columns were detected in the statement.

Comment: @Sean Lange The data in the database tables is out of my hands i can only access it with a read only account

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may first assign the result of you first query into a variable and then use that variable to build a query to run that later -

```
Declare @query Nvarchar(max),
        @collections Nvarchar(max)

SELECT @collections = c.collectionsql 
FROM dbo.collections  AS c 
where c.description = '9-nummers laatste 9 maanden geen afzet'


set @query ='Select * from dbo.article as Article ' + @collections;

exec ( @query  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right way using dynamic query and use of Exec function. You need to select using top 1 for sub query as follow.

```
create table #Collections (Collectionsql varchar(250), description varchar(250))

insert into #Collections values('where (demand13 <= 0) and (demand14 <= 0)','9-nummers laatste 9 maanden geen afzet');


create table #Article  ( demand13 int, demand14 int)

insert into #Article values(-1,-2)
insert into #Article values(-10,-2)
insert into #Article values(-1,12)

Declare @query Nvarchar(max)

set @query ='Select * from #Article ' + (SELECT top 1 c.collectionsql 
FROM #Collections  AS c 
where c.description = '9-nummers laatste 9 maanden geen afzet'
 )

 print @query

 Exec(@query)

 drop table #Article
 drop table #Collections
```

OutPut

```
 demand13   demand14
-1              -2
-10              -2
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem was not in the SQL-query but in the connection to the database. it was using an odbc connection which gave te problem. now using SQLNCLI11